# Basic Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there are two lakes located on a stream. Clean water flows into the first lake, then the water from the first lake flows into the second lake, and then water from the second lake flows further downstream. The in and out flow from each lake is 500 liters per hour. The first lake contains 100 thousand liters of water and the second lake contains 200 thousand liters of water. A truck with 500 kg of toxic substance crashes into the first lake. Assume that the water is being continually mixed perfectly by the stream. a) Find the concentration of toxic substance as a function of time in both lakes. b) When will the concentration in the first lake be below 0.001 kg per liter? c) When will the concentration in the second lake be maximal?

I'm completely stuck on how to do the question.

Comment: Start by figuring out what your dependent variable(s) are (the independent one is time). Then, you can worry about writing down ODEs for them.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll help with the first lake.

For the sake of understanding, let's call the respective volume of lakes $Q_1,\,Q_2$, the flows are $v$, the mass of poison in lakes $m_i$. Initial mass of poison $m$.

The concentration in the first lake is $\frac{m_1}{Q_1}$, hence the flow brings in $v\Delta t$ of fresh water and carries away $v\Delta t \frac{m_1}{Q_1}$ of toxic substance. Thus, $\Delta m_1 = v\Delta t \frac{m_1}{Q_1}$, or, in other words, $$\frac{d}{dt}m_1(t) = m_1(t)\frac{v}{Q_1},\quad m_1(0)=m.$$ We can solve this equation.

Can you take it from here and apply the same method to obtain the equation for the second lake?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused about the question now.
Is it asking to find one equation that encompasses both lakes or two separate equations for each lake?

And for your equation, isn't m(t) the mass of poison, not the concentration then?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I have the same question, m(t) is the mass of the poison but the question is asking for the concentration. How can we change the function so it's about concentration?

Comment: @user59036 As the volume of the lake is constant, you can safely divide both parts of the equation by $Q_1$ to obtain the equation for concentration $c_1$: $\frac{d}{dt}c_1(t) = c_1(t)\frac{v}{Q_1},\quad c_1(0)=m/Q_1.$

Comment: @AlexChim the question asks to find the system of equations (the concentration in the second lake depends on the concentration in the first one). But in our case we can write and solve the equation for the first lake separately. For the equation on concentration, see my previous comment.