# Pollution of lakes, differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose there are two lakes located on a stream. Clean water flows into the first lake, then the water from the first lake flows into the second lake, and then water from the second lake flows further downstream. The in and out flow from each lake is 500 liters per hour. The first lake contains 100 thousand liters of water and the second lake contains 200 thousand liters of water. A truck with 500 kg of toxic substance crashes into the first lake. Assume that the water is being continually mixed perfectly by the stream. a) Find the concentration of toxic substance as a function of time in both lakes. b) When will the concentration in the first lake be below 0.001 kg per liter? c) When will the concentration in the second lake be maximal?

Some hints I got:

Let's call the respective volume of lakes $Q_1,\,Q_2$, the flows are $v$, the mass of poison in lakes $m_i$. Initial mass of poison $m$.

The concentration in the first lake is $\frac{m_1}{Q_1}$, hence the flow brings in $v\Delta t$ of fresh water and carries away $v\Delta t \frac{m_1}{Q_1}$ of toxic substance. Thus, $\Delta m_1 = v\Delta t \frac{m_1}{Q_1}$, or, in other words, $$\frac{d}{dt}m_1(t) = m_1(t)\frac{v}{Q_1},\quad m_1(0)=m.$$

However the question is asking "find the concentration of the toxic substance as a function of time". How can I change the function so is in terms of the concentration rather than the mass of the toxic substance?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to express everything in therms of $\frac{m_i(t)}{Q_i}$. Then why not just define the variable $c_i(t)=\frac{m_i(t)}{Q_i}$ (concentration) and then you have $\frac{d}{dt}c_i(t)=c_i(t)\frac{v}{Q_i}$.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501769/basic-differential-equations#comment1077517_501769 .